# How can I install template from 3rd party to Keynote?

Tags: macbook-pro, keynote, iwork, 3rd-party, template

After downloading a template for my Keynote program, I can't seem to install it correctly so that I can utilize the 200+ slides that are included when I wish to add a new slide in the presentation.

I have the latest software of El Capitan and the latest version of Keynote installed.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Purchased "Eureka - Minimal Keynote Template" from this site (http://graphicriver.net/item/eureka-minimal-keynote-template/15099332) and downloaded files.
2. Folder downloaded is split up into different sub folders: 1 Documentation, 2 Presentation, 3 Vector Icons, 4 Double Exposure PSD. 
   From folder 2 there are two files named Eureka - 16x9 - MAIN.key and when opening them in Keynote, on the left sidebar 200+ slides are displayed (these are all the slide templates that I wish to utilize when creating new presentations).
3. So I choose "Save Theme" and add it to the "Theme Chooser", but when opening it from the "Theme Chooser" I only get the two master slides - one white and one black" to choose from when clicking "add slide".
4. So I go back and check the Eureka - 16x9 - MAIN.key that I first opened, and see that when clicking "add slide" in this one, I also only have the two options of the black and the white slide here.

[image: screenshot of sidebar and "add slide"]

So this is where I am puzzled - should not the template I have purchased when saved give me the opportunity of finding all the 200+ template slides in the slide navigator when I click "add slide"? This is what I want - so I can choose between the 200+ of them when creating a new presentation based on the template. So how can I do this?

Do I have to save all the 200+ slides as master slides, and if so how do I do this?

Or are there another solution?

I have been googling for hours now, and all I can seem to find are that I have to add the downloaded file to /library/application support/Keynote/templates , but there are no /keynote/templates to be found in my library.

Answer (score 1):

The specific location where the files are stored is:

~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Keynote/Data/Library/Application Support/User Templates

OR

You can just use the Save Theme > Add Theme to Chooser option to achieve the same result.

[image: custom-keynote-theme]

However, you will need to add the missing slides to your set of Master Slides manually.

### Adding New Master Slides

To do that:

1. Go to a unique slide that came with the theme and copy the unique elements
2. Under View, Select Edit Master Slides
3. Make sure you can view the Navigator on the left
4. Right-click (two-finger click) over the Navigator and make a new Master Slide
5. On the new Master Slide - clear out any default elements if it's not blank
6. Paste the unique elements from the slide copied into step #1
7. Rename the new master slide to something memorable about the content
8. Exit the master slide editor (Done button)
   (Repeat for as many slides that you want to use with the template)

When finished you should be able to save and use the updated Keynote template normally.

Keynote used: version 8.0.1 (5579)

> Missing fonts - Lots of 3rd party templates come without the fonts.
>   You'll need to install these or choose substitutes and then reboot to
>   have Keynote recognize all the fonts.